Why does Arabic text read from PDF gets shuffled while it appears to be in order in List<String> while inspecting in debugging console
I am reading an Arabic PDF file via PDFBox library line by line. When inspecting debugging console I am able to see all lines are in order, but when the entire list contents are viewed in one line, it seems text is getting shuffled up and not in the order. Also library is reading out some additional characters from PDF which are not visible with eyes and causing the PDF read accuracy issues. As visible in Image2, when we view the elements based on index, they seem to be read correctly, but when viewed in one line view they are shuffled. Can anyone explain this abnormal behavior?
PDF Image

Debugging console

I tried with different methods like trying to eliminate extra chars, reversing the order of line to see if the text is mirror imaged but nothing worked out.
public List<String> extractPageText(int pageNumber, PDDocument document) {
  List<String> currentPageLines = new ArrayList<>();
  PDFTextStripper stripper1 = null;
  String[] pageLines = null;
  try {
    PDFTextStripperByArea stripper2 = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
    Rectangle2D rect = new java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float(10, 10, 580, 690);
    stripper2.addRegion("region", rect);
    stripper2.extractRegions(document.getPage(pageNumber));
    String textForRegion = stripper2.getTextForRegion("region");
    pageLines = textForRegion.split("\n");
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  for (String currentPageline : pageLines) {
    currentPageLines.add(currentPageline.trim());
  }
  return currentPageLines;
}


Well what are the invisible characters? They might be things that change the display order such as U+202E (Right to Left Override)

I think your real problem is what you do with the List<String> that method extractPageText returns. I'm guessing it does not behave the way you want it to. If that is correct, then I suggest that you [edit] your question and state what you are trying to do with the List<String> that method extractPageText returns along with what you want it to do and what it is actually doing.
